# how to add forgot password field using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am really new to rails.  im using devise gem. now,im trying to implement forget password field in my application.I have been working for hours, but I haven't really had any results. How do I set this up? I am using rails 4

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, #:registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  enum role: [:creator, :editor, :curator,  :super_admin]
  enum status: {:inprogress => 1, :completed => 2}

  #has_many :albums
  has_many :order_states
  has_many :products, through: :order_states

  has_many :tagging
  has_many :pictures, through: :tagging

  def self.authenticate(username, password)
    user = User.find_for_authentication(email: username)
    if user
      user.valid_password?(password) ? user : nil
    else
      nil
    end

  end

  def generate_authentication_token
    token = SecureRandom.hex
    self.update_columns(auth_token: token, token_created_at: Time.zone.now)
    token
  end

end
```

Comment: Why you create authenticate and generate_auth methods? Devise allready have by default the "forgot password" option. I think in the module "Recoverable". If you need other otion explain more plz.

Comment: i have created that generate_auth method for generation of token to API

Comment: you read the devise document? http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable